# Filter Webparts in SharePoint 2013?

Tags: sharepoint-online

Can we use `Or` condition in SharePoint list filter?

My requirement is: Based on 4 columns I have to filter the records.

Can anyone explain this?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by applying filters to your list *view*. Either take an existing view and edit it or create a new view and in the view's settings you will find a "Filter" section.

[image]